# How to get the NEW text in TextChanged?

Tags: c#, events, text, textbox

In a TextBox I'm monitoring the text changes. I need to check the text before doing some stuff. But I can only check the old text in the moment. How can I get the new Text ?

```
private void textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // need to check the new text
}
```

I know .NET Framework 4.5 has the new `TextChangedEventArgs` class but I have to use .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: Are you using web forms or win forms?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50067245/9285072

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Getting the NEW value**

You can just use the `Text` property of the `TextBox`. If this event is used for multiple text boxes then you will want to use the `sender` parameter to get the correct `TextBox` control, like so...

```
private void textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if(textBox != null)
    {
        string theText = textBox.Text;
    }
}
```

---

**Getting the OLD value**

For those looking to get the old value, you will need to keep track of that yourself. I would suggest a simple variable that starts out as empty, and changes at the end of each event:

```
string oldValue = "";
private void textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if(textBox != null)
    {
        string theText = textBox.Text;

        // Do something with OLD value here.

        // Finally, update the old value ready for next time.
        oldValue = theText;
    }
}
```

You could create your own TextBox control that inherits from the built-in one, and adds this additional functionality, if you plan to use this a lot.

Comment: I could swear just a moment ago I've seen only the old version of Text in this event. Now Text is changed BEFORE the event. So the question is redundant now.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [textbox events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events.aspx) such as [KeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), KeyPress etc. For example:

```
private void textbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Do whatever you need.
}
```

Maybe these can help you achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the older .net fw 2.0 you should still have the new and old value in the eventArgs if not in the textbox.text property itself since the event is fired after and not during the text changing.

If you want to do stuff while the text is being changed then try the KeyUp event rather then the Changed.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void stIDTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (stIDTextBox.TextLength == 6)
    {
        studentId = stIDTextBox.Text; // Here studentId is a variable.

        // this process is used to read textbox value automatically.
        // In this case I can read textbox until the char or digit equal to 6.
    }
}
```