# How to get input value of dynamically added textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, linq, dynamic-programming

I have a simple form in asp.net, where i add some data to database, using LINQ to SQL.

On button click, i dynamically load few more textboxes. All of those textboxes have counter and get different id's on each load.

I want to know, how to get input values from those dynamically added textboxes, so i can input that data into database.

Meaning, that if user types in textbox "lord of the rings", i want to get that data in codebehind and add it to database.

It's easy to get in on basic form where i just do it like: inputValue.Text, but with different id's i'm kinda lost...

**My code for dynamically adding textboxes**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
        TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
        TextBox tb3 = new TextBox();
        TextBox tb4 = new TextBox();
        tb1.ID = "inputAuthor" + counter;
        tb2.ID = "inputBookName" + counter;
        tb3.ID = "inputCategory" + counter;

        LiteralControl lineBreak = new LiteralControl("<br/>");
        ph1.Controls.Add(tb1);
        ph1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
        controlIdList.Add(tb1.ID);
        ph1.Controls.Add(tb2);
        ph1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
        controlIdList.Add(tb2.ID);
        ph1.Controls.Add(tb3);
        ph1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
        controlIdList.Add(tb3.ID);
        ph1.Controls.Add(tb4);
        ph1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
        controlIdList.Add(tb4.ID);
        ViewState["controlIdList"] = controlIdList;  
    }
```

**UPDATE**

**dynamically added textboxes**

```
<input name="dnn$ctr1365$Author$inputAuthor1" id="dnn_ctr1365_Author_inputAuthor1" type="text">
<input name="dnn$ctr1365$BookName$inputBookName1" id="dnn_ctr1365_BookName_inputBookName1" type="text">
<input name="dnn$ctr1365$Category$inputCategory1" id="dnn_ctr1365_Category_inputCategory1" type="text">
```

**default .aspx form**

```
<input name="dnn$ctr1365$Author$inputAuthor" id="dnn_ctr1365_Author_inputAuthor" class="form-control" style="background:#fff" type="text">
```

Comment: please provide html that rendered at browser.

Comment: do you mean this? (please see update). and oh btw, it's dnn module i'm creating @Bharat

Comment: ok, so i think these id is client id, and just add one more tag in that html i.e Runat = "server" or make it a asp:net text box

Comment: how do i get input values now? @Bharat

Answer (score 0):

Your flow should be like below.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dnn_ctr1365_Author_inputAuthor" name="dnn$ctr1365$Author$inputAuthor" class="form-control" style="background:#fff" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And retrieve data from backend.

```
string value = dnn_ctr1365_Author_inputAuthor.Text.toString();
```

something like this will help you.
I have not tested that code but just wright it as flow should be.

check this links they will help you to understand asp.net webform controls.

https://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2008/10/textbox-example-how-to-use-textbox.html

Comment: but that will only get value of my default textbox, not the value of dynamically added textboxes which have different id's...

Comment: ok, now i understand your issue, i think it's not a good way to bind this type of controls. still your code runs if you manage to add runat code in your html.

Comment: was never difficult to get value of a textbox from codebehind... it's difficult to get values of dynamically created textboxes because i don't know how to loop through their id's

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly. You are generating dynamic textbox at code-behind. and your textbox able to notify change at the backend.

To do this. Firstly you have to accept that there is no rich pool of eventHandler for you at .Net like winform. There is only TextChanged event and it behaved like onBlur or mouseLeave.

To achieve this your dynamic textBox will be something like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
    tb1.ID = "t1";    
    tb1.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    tb1.AutoPostBack = true;
    addEvent(tb1,tb1.ID);
    panel.Controls.Add(tb1);
}

private void addEvent(TextBox tb1,string id)
{
    tb1.TextChanged += (senders, eventArgs) =>
    {
        //do Something with the ID
    };    
}
```

the main point is to set AutoPostBack to true, so that t1's TextChanged can be catched at the backended.

After that, t1_TextChanged will be triggered for each change of your dynamic textbox. So that you can play with your database afterwards.

Comment: what do you mean do something with id? can you post an example?

Comment: there is few issues for the host, 1: generate textBox dynamically, 2: the backend able to notify the event from the textBox, //do something with the ID. which is the communication with database and data from backend, which is not part of this question i think

Comment: with this approach , you can generate any number of dynamic textBox, and addEvent to each of them, and each of them can //do Something with the ID, and you can also get the text of within the event, you may want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337057/how-to-get-the-new-text-in-textchanged

Comment: will try and report back