# Replacing specific words of RichTextBox text in winforms with another textbox value

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have a RichTextBox which has a text. The text will have variables inside it that can be changed by the user, like [var1] and [var2]. I want to let the user change the variable values by typing the variable value in a separate text box but want the change to be reflected live so as he is typing the value of the RichTextBox is updated.

**I tried using this:**

```cs
private void VariableTextBox_TextChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    string variableName = $"[{textBox!.Name}]";

    rtNotes.Text = rtNotes.Text.Replace(variableName, textBox.Text);
}
```

But when the user types the first letter, the old variable name is replaced, so the Replace function won't work and any other letters typed won't update the text.

I also tried using a global variable called templateNotes which I set its value to the RichTextBox value at form load:

```
private void VariableTextBox_TextChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    string variableName = $"[{textBox!.Name}]";

    rtNotes.Text = templateNotes.Replace(variableName , textBox.Text);
}
```

It is working as expected, but it doesn't work when there are multiple variables, each one having its own TextBox as changing the second variable will reset the first one value.

Comment: Does this answers your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337057/how-to-get-the-new-text-in-textchanged

Comment: @Steven It doesn't sadly as the value keeps changing as the user types

Comment: Since you're targeting at least .NET 6, you could use the `\v` RTF command, which hides a section of text (e.g., `{... Some {\v text}here\par}` shows `some here`), so you can add your *[placeholder]* there, then show the same *placeholder* (using a different case, maybe, so you can specify `RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase` with the `Find()` method) as visible text. Then you can replace the visible text of the placeholder with your own. The actual placeholder will retain position if the rest of the text can change

Comment: The `Find()` method can of course find hidden text